# Is it common to see directors acting in their own films?

Tags: directors

There are a few movies I can note where their directors also played a role in their films:

- Orson Welles tended to star in many of his films, but that was during the 40's
- Roman Polanski  played the role of the man who cut Jack Nicholson's nose in *Chinatown*, but *Chinatown* was released in 1974
- The most recent film I can think of where this happened was when Quentin Tarantino played Jimmy in *Pulp Fiction*, which was released in 1994

I can't really think of any recent movies where directors did this. Is it common to see directors acting in their own films these days?

Comment: How do you define "common"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a very common occurrence. To quote a recent instance, Jon Favreau played the chauffeur in both Iron Man and Iron Man 2. Quentin Tarantino acted in Grindhouse, From Dusk Til Dawn, and had several other films. Clint Eastwood appeared in Gran Torino and Million Dollar Baby. I could cite even more if I could recollect year by year.

[This Wikipedia article could be of some help.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_directors_who_appear_in_their_own_films)

Comment: Another modern example: British actor/writer/director [Noel Clarke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel_Clarke) has a major acting part in many of the films he's directed.

Comment: M. Night Shyamalan appears in most (maybe all?) of the films he directs.

Comment: Well, *Favreau* and *Eastwood* also do (or did) acting as their primary job. On these lines you could also mention *George Clooney*. *Shyamalan* and *Tarantino* are much better examples, being mainly directors and not appearing in other movies than their own (though one could argue about *Tarantino*). And by the way, wasn't *From Dusk Till Dawn* and *Planet Terror* (for I don't think he was in *Death Proof*) from *Rodriguez*. I know they are pals, but well. But +1 for the Wiki link.

Comment: That list has (rough guess) approximately 250 movies where a director appeared in his own movie. In recent years, Hollywood produces approx. 600 movies per year. I don't know whether that is a more or less steady number over the decades, but let's assume so. So assuming we're talking about the period 1960-2010, then a "back of the envelope" calculation -- (250*100)/((2010-1960)*600) -- puts the % at... [less than one percent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28250*100%29%2F%28%282010-1960%29*600%29). I wouldn't call that "a very common occurrence".

Comment: @BCdotWEB Your statistics are skewed.  You assume everyone has seen every film.  It is more likely that the majority of movie-watchers have seen closer to 1% of all films, in which a high percentage of those have had their directors acting.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger "You assume everyone has seen every film." Whether this happens is irrelevant. The question never mentions that only the top X of movies should be considered, nor does this answer. Were that the case, then I'd love to see those numbers, but I bet it is still nowhere near "very common" because plenty of the movies mentioned in that list are not in the top 10 or top 20 most popular movies of their year.

Comment: @BCdotWEB  You just made another poor assumption.  Why do these movies need to be seen within the first year of their release to qualify for your assertion?  To put it plainly, the movies listed are iconic, groundbreaking and/or have achieved cult status.  Over time they are more likely to be seen than other movies of their year's release.

Answer (score 7):

Speaking as a director-

To step back, one has to consider what the job of directing is. It's a story teller who sees the big picture. Directors have to be able to create the scene and the tone with picture, framing, editing, and of course acting.

Some directors are stronger at pulling the best performance out of an actor; some are better at setting the scene. But inevitably, everything you see they've had their hand in.

Being part of the final product, even for just a split second lets them take the ride they are building. Chris "X-Files" Carter went so far as to have Ten-Thirteen Production's Logo include a voice saying, "I Made This!"

Finally, who better to figure out where to put a little bit of self-homagistic fun into a film than the person directing it.

Not every director will have the desire to do so, and there may be many cases of directors in films that haven't been caught; but it's very common and very likely to continue.